# Someone is down-voting my old low-scored questions in Academia

Tags: discussion, etiquette

This question may not be well fitted here. But I am wondering why someone is perhaps intentionally down-voting my old low-scored questions asked here?

I wouldn't surprise if the down-votes appears at the time I asked the question. But the down-voter is targeting my old low-scored questions. I would appreciate if the same down-voter gives some up-votes to my high-scored questions. But I can't see it.

Although I don't care the votes or scores at all, but still wondering the possible reasons for it.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think all these votes are coming from the same person? Or that you, specifically, are being targeted? It's not so unusual for old posts to get some votes as people come across them through search (nobody seems to complain when an old post gets an upvote...)

Comment: I guess it. Because in my last 2.5 years, I had never seen any such behavior. My questions are down-voted very very rarely and that to at the time I asked (may be 3 or 4 in total until 26 Feb, 2018). But in last 15-17 days I had got 4 down-votes in my old low-scored questions.

Comment: I'm tempted to take a look on your answers/questions to see the quality and eventually vote (up or down). Would it be against the rules the distribution of votes through the posts of one particular user if the votes were not biased?

Comment: Great @TheDoctor.. I appreciate it.. But why only old low-score questions... For your information, I got only down-votes in those days (from 26 Feb - 15 Mar).. if someone had a look to check the quality, do you mean he was interested in my low-scored questions only?

Comment: @TheDoctor Yes, that would be against the rules.

Answer (score 6):

Targeted voting, whether up or down, is against SE community guidelines and, when detected, generally reversed.

Comment: Yes, happened to me - but the moderators spotted it before me and I only knew when they sent me a message saying something like « block voting reversed » . You mods do a good job - thanks.

Comment: Might be worth noting that targeted upvoting is also not allowed. (Re: "I would appreciate if the same down-voter gives some up-votes to my high-scored questions", if that happened it would also be against the rules and reversed if detected.)

Comment: @Solar that was an automated thing, thank the SE devs for that not the mods :)

Comment: Thanks to the SE Devs then for that and the mods for what they do !

Answer (score 6):

Some kinds of targeted voting are detected automatically and reversed by the system (see this [Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)).

In other cases, where it isn't the kind of pattern that is automatically detected, moderators can ask a Stack Exchange employee to take a closer look at a voting pattern. I have just done this for you. If there is targeted voting going on, they'll reverse it (and let the mods know who was responsible, so we can take care of that). If a few weeks pass and nothing happens, it means they've checked it out and confirmed that it wasn't targeted voting.